# elements overlap when animating ngIf

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular5, css-animations

I'm trying to animate `div`'s when toggled using `*ngIf`.

I assume the problem I'm encountering is a rather known delay/timing problem in animation, yet I couldn't figure out a legit solution.

1) When the existing element starts his leaving animation, he is still in the DOM.

2) the entering element starts his animation during this time.

3) **The Problem** is that by the time the first element finishes the animation and is removed from the DOM, the second element is already visibile thus creates a UI glitch

The following code is not mine but it demonstrate my problem.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']).
controller('ctrl', function(){});
```

```css
.fade-element-in.ng-enter {
  transition: 0.8s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-element-in-init .fade-element-in.ng-enter {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-element-in.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-element-in.ng-leave {
  transition: 0.3s linear all;
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-element-in.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <a href="" ng-click="showMe = !showMe">Click me</a>
  <div class="fade-element-in" ng-if="showMe">
    SomeContent
  </div>
  <div class="fade-element-in" ng-if="!showMe">
    SomeOtherContent
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to have one item at a time you can set it to `position: absolute`
so that they don't affect each others positioning

we can go further by adding `ng-class` to add the animation

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']).
controller('ctrl', function() {});
```

```css
.fade-element-in.ng-enter {
  transition: 0.8s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-element-in-init .fade-element-in.ng-enter {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-element-in.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-element-in.ng-leave {
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-element-in.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <a href="" ng-click="showMe = !showMe">Click me</a>
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-class="{'fade-element-in': showMe}" ng-if="showMe">
      SomeContent
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-class="{'fade-element-in': !showMe}" ng-if="!showMe">
      SomeOtherContent
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! this seems to solve the problem for most parts ... but is this really the most ideal way to handle this? I feel like there is a more elegant solution that I am missing

Comment: glad to help if you just use ng-class to add the class it will just fade in the item i feel like this is a better way of handling

Comment: @OmriBtian whats more elegant than one line of CSS and an ng-class?